# How can I use vue.js and wordpress rest api to template a specific page?

Tags: vue.js, wordpress-rest-api

Does anyone know how to expand this theme ( https://github.com/gilbitron/wp-rest-theme ) in order to theme specific pages? For example, I would like to create a page called "Menu" which has a unique navigation to click through to child pages Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, etc without reload. I'm used to creating individual .php files to theme specific pages to my liking via page-{slug}.php - Is there an equivalent workflow using vue.js and wp rest api?

Instead of using page-menu.php to customize the /menu page, I would imagine I'd need to create something like a menu-page.vue file and add a custom method to specifically call that page in order to template it.

I can't find any examples of this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was add a field using Advanced Custom Fields that determined which template the page should use.  I wrapped the display in a component called `PageContent` that looks like this:

```
<div :is="page.template"
     :page="page"
     v-if="!$loadingRouteData"
     transition="fade"
     transition-mode="out-in">
</div>
```

router:

```
  '/:slug': {
    component: PageContent,
    name: 'Page'
  }
```

So when someone navigates to that route, I fetch the page based on the `slug` param.  The `page` variable then has a `template` attribute through ACF, which determines the component to display and defaults to a generic page:

```
if(pages[0].acf.template){
  return pages[0].acf.template;
}
return 'page'
```

You need the WP JSON API plugin as well as the ACF plugin that adds ACF data to the json

[My site](https://jeffsiebach.com) uses this setup, happy to share more code if you have more questions.

Comment: You need to share this. You need to! :-) Great stuff